# Is $32561698$ divisible by $12$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

So i was given this question. Is $32561698$ divisible by $12$?

Here is my attempted solution:

First check divisibility by $3$:

$3 + 2 + 5 + 6 + 1 + 6 + 9 + 8 = 40$ which is not divisible by 3

The last two digits is $98$ which is not divisible by 4 so it is not divisible by 12.

I saw this kind of solution style on this website where it shows divisibility by 12 https://www.easycalculation.com/funny/shortcuts/divide-by-12.php

Is this correct?

Comment: The solution using modular arithmetic is the same. If our number is $N$, then $N\equiv 98\pmod{100}$, so $N\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, and therefore in particular it cannot be $\equiv 0\pmod{12}$.

Comment: Actually you are done after considering it is not divisible by one of the divisors prime factors. A number cannot be made an integer after dividing by a new integer after it has left the integers.

Comment: It's enough to show that it's not divisible by 3. Your answer is perfect ! Good job ! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, and in fact you've done twice as much work as you need to. It's enough to have shown that the number is not divisible by 3, and separately it's enough to have shown that the number is not divisible by 4. (The 4-divisibility test is easier in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for but

The easy (2-digit) multiples of 12 are 12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96 so

$32,561,698 \equiv 8,561,698 \mod 12$ (so $24,000,000 \equiv 0 \mod 12$)

So

$32,561,698 \equiv 24,000,000 + 8,561,698 \equiv$

$7,200,000 + 1,361,698 \equiv 1,200,000 + 161,698 \equiv 12,000 + 41,698 \equiv$

$36,000 + 5,698 \equiv 4,800 + 898 \equiv 840 + 58 \equiv$

$48 + 10 \equiv 10 \mod 12$